# Stylized initials cause gaps in the text

Tags: html, css

I'm using these google fonts in my web page (I'm also using Bootstrap - don't know if that changes anything, I'm kinda new to this coding thing):

```css
.initial {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Euphoria Script', cursive;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html><head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Euphoria+Script&subset=latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&subset=latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></head>
  <body>
    <p><span class="initial">S</span>ome text here. And some more. We seriously need a lot of text.</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Problem is that, since the euphoria font is taller, when the line breaks there's more space between the first line and the second than between all the other lines. Is there some workaround? I don't care if the text is near the initial or indented.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Specify the line height on your text, so all text will have the same height despite the difference in the font size. Try this:

```css
.initial {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Euphoria Script', cursive;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html><head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Euphoria+Script&subset=latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&subset=latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></head>
  <body>
    <p><span class="initial">S</span>ome text here. And some more. We seriously need a lot of text. And some more. We seriously need a lot of text. And some more. We seriously need a lot of text. And some more. We seriously need a lot of text. And some more. We seriously need a lot of text. And some more. We seriously need a lot of text.</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You had the right idea but I had to add line-height to the .initial too...? Anyway, this worked great!

Comment: That's strange. `.initial` is a `span` and should inherit the `line-height` style from it's parent `p` exactly like in my code snippet. But I'm glad you sorted it out.

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought... I probably goofed up somewhere else! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Consider using float: left (+ first-letter selector if you don't care with supporting old browsers:

```
p:first-letter {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color: red;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/zr8qarw9/